# Multiple one to one relations between entities

Tags: codefluent

In our model, we have implemented a one to one relation between entity A and B, as in:

`<cf:property name="For" typeName="{0}.B">`

We now want to add a new (different) one to one relation between B and A. E.g.:

`<cf:property name="Links" typeName="{0}.A">`

Apparently, codefluent seems to consider this relation to be a single one to one relation, instead of 2 different one to one relations.

How should this be modeled?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained here: [Multiple Association Relationship](https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/Entities_Relationships_MultipleAssociation.html), so in your case you would do something like this for example. Note in this case, you must declare both sides of relations with properties.

in A:

```
<cf:property name="For" typeName="{0}.B" relationPropertyName="Back">
<cf:property name="For2" typeName="{0}.B" relationPropertyName="Back2">
```

in B:

```
<cf:property name="Back" typeName="{0}.A" relationPropertyName="For">
<cf:property name="Back2" typeName="{0}.A" relationPropertyName="For2">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We do not really have any need for the 2nd side of the relation, ie the Back2 & For2 relation. Might relationSynchronize = false be of any use for this issue?

Comment: relationSynchronize=false is unrelated. It just mean a 1:1 relation will not be synchronized at runtime (synchronized means if you define one side, like A.id->B.Aid, the other one B.id->A.Bid will be set also)